# check for IOMMU support on linux

Tags: linux, pci, iommu

I'd like to verify on any given Linux machine if PCI passthrough is supported. After a bit of googling, I found that I should rather check if IOMMU is supported, and I did so by running:

```
dmesg | grep IOMMU
```

If it supports IOMMU (and not IOMMUv2), I would get:

```
IOMMU                                                          
[    0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.049734] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 0
[    0.049735] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 9 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 0
[    1.286567] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <jroedel@suse.de>
[    1.286568] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
```

...where `DMAR: IOMMU enabled` is what I'm looking for.

Now, if the machine has been running for days without a reboot, that first message `[    0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled`  might not appear any more in the log with the previous command.

Is there any way to check for IOMMU support when that message disappears from the log?

Comment: Kernel dmesg is logged to some file in `/var/log`: kern.log and/or messages. Check also /sys/class/iommu directory

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better then checking the kernel log is using the command: virt-host-validate. I agree this belongs on unix.stackexchange.com, but this question is still the first hit when googling for 'linux check iommu support'.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that command. In its 1.2.20 version it doesn't tell me much, but I just checked with version 2.2.0 and it's a lot more helpful:  `QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : WARN (IOMMU appears to be disabled in kernel. Add intel_iommu=on to kernel cmdline arguments)
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since 2014 enabled iommu are registered in /sys (sysfs) special file system as class `iommu` (documented at [ABI/testing/sysfs-class-iommu](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-iommu)):
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4345491/ "[2/3] iommu/intel: Make use of IOMMU sysfs support" - June 12, 2014

> Register our DRHD IOMMUs, cross link devices, and provide a base set
>   of attributes for the IOMMU.  ...
>   On a typical desktop system, this provides the following (pruned):
>
> ```
> $ find /sys | grep dmar
> /sys/devices/virtual/iommu/dmar0
> ...
> /sys/class/iommu/dmar0
> /sys/class/iommu/dmar1
> ```

The code is `iommu_device_create` (http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.5/ident/iommu_device_create, around 4.5) or `iommu_device_sysfs_add` (http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/ident/iommu_device_sysfs_add) in more recent kernels.

```
/*
 * Create an IOMMU device and return a pointer to it.  IOMMU specific
 * attributes can be provided as an attribute group, allowing a unique
 * namespace per IOMMU type.
 */
struct device *iommu_device_create(struct device *parent, void *drvdata,
                   const struct attribute_group **groups,
                   const char *fmt, ...)
```

Registration is done only for enabled IOMMU. DMAR:

```
if (intel_iommu_enabled) {
    iommu->iommu_dev = iommu_device_create(NULL, iommu,
                           intel_iommu_groups,
                           "%s", iommu->name);
```

AMD IOMMU:

```
static int iommu_init_pci(struct amd_iommu *iommu)
{ ...
    if (!iommu->dev)
        return -ENODEV;
...
    iommu->iommu_dev = iommu_device_create(&iommu->dev->dev, iommu,
                           amd_iommu_groups, "ivhd%d",
                           iommu->index);
```

Intel:

```
int __init intel_iommu_init(void)
{ ...
    pr_info("Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O\n");
...
    for_each_active_iommu(iommu, drhd)
        iommu->iommu_dev = iommu_device_create(NULL, iommu,
                               intel_iommu_groups,
                               "%s", iommu->name);
```

With 4.11 linux kernel version `iommu_device_sysfs_add` is [referenced in many IOMMU drivers](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/ident/iommu_device_sysfs_add), so checking /sys/class/iommu is better (more universal) way to programmatically detect enabled IOMMU than parsing `dmesg` output or searching in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/messages` for driver-specific enable messages:

> Referenced in 10 files:
>
> - drivers/iommu/amd_iommu_init.c, line 1640
> - drivers/iommu/arm-smmu-v3.c, line 2709
> - drivers/iommu/arm-smmu.c, line 2163
> - drivers/iommu/dmar.c, line 1083
> - drivers/iommu/exynos-iommu.c, line 623
> - drivers/iommu/intel-iommu.c, line 4878
> - drivers/iommu/iommu-sysfs.c, line 57
> - drivers/iommu/msm_iommu.c, line 797
> - drivers/iommu/mtk_iommu.c, line 581

Comment: Thanks. So ideally I would just have to check for a given PCI device if its PCI address appears in `/sys/devices/virtual/iommu/dmar0/devices/` ?   I don't understand why you include several snippets of code in the rest of your answer.

Comment: Also check your PCI folder in sysfs, it may has iommu or iommu_group links to the specific IOMMU. (Checking for DMAR is not too portable, it will not work on ARM). Code snippets to show that iommu files/dirs in sysfs will be registered only when IOMMU is enabled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I noticed that on machines where PCI passthrough is not supported, the folder `/sys/class/iommu` exists but it's empty, whereas on machines where it is supported it contains a folder `dmar0`, which itself contains `devices  intel-iommu  power  subsystem  uevent`. So checking if `/sys/class/iommu` is empty or not should already yield some answer. How should I perform the second check in `sysfs`? I'm not sure I understand where and what to check... Thanks!!!

Comment: Ricky, yes, the `/sys/class/iommu` folder is almost always there (when sysfs is mounted). You should do ls (readdir) of its subfolders:  `ls -l /sys/class/iommu/*`, or event  `ls -l /sys/class/iommu/*/devices` to find devices which have iommu enabled.

Comment: will DMAR present in AMD also?